# Create a for loop that will iterate a certain number of times in Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am in a situation in which I would like to be able to have a component or helper that would allow me to iterate a number of times and output the enclosed block each time.  Something like this:

```
{{#incremented-for 2}}
    block to output
{{/incremented-for}}
```

I tried to set this up as a component, but was not able to figure out a way to make it work.  I also tried to set it up as a helper, and was able to find some code that seems like it should work:

```
export function incrementedFor(n, block) {
    var accum = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        accum += block.fn(i);
    return accum;
}

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(incrementedFor);
```

but i get an error that says:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: registerBoundHelper-generated helpers do not support use with Handlebars blocks.
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this approach might not be working or, even better, a better way to do this in Ember-cli?

Comment: which Ember version are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the docs, bound helpers do not support blocks - see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#toc_use-with-blocks-not-supported)

You can create a `increment-for` component as follows. Create a component that expects a `times` property. Then, you can have a `numOfTimes` property that returns an array with length `times`. Finally, you can use a combination of `#each` and `yield` helpers to display your content.

Component code:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  numOfTimes: Ember.computed('times', function() {
    const times = parseInt(this.get('times'));
    return new Array(times);
  })
});
```

Component template:

```
{{#each numOfTimes as |time|}}
  {{ yield }}
{{/each}}
```

Component usage:

```
{{#increment-for times=2 }}
  <div>How goes it?</div>
{{/increment-for}}
```

Working solution [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tosese/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 10):

As a complement to the answer of @Kalman and you would use the [ember-composable-helper](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) addon, it's even simpler.

By using the [repeat](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#repeat) helper, a loop is easily created:

```
{{#each (repeat 3) as |empty|}}
  I will be rendered 3 times
{{/each}}
```