# looping over an array returned from function

Tags: ember.js

As you'll see in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864749/create-a-for-loop-that-will-iterate-a-certain-number-of-times-in-ember-cli) it is possible to loop with `{{#each}}` in a component template over the return value of a component function that is an array.  For convience sake, I copy that code here at the very bottom.

I tried to do something similar. In my template, I use a component and pass it an object with key values

```
{{'my-comp' kvobject=mykvobject}}
```

In `components/my-comp.js`, I create a function that returns an array

```
   keyvalues: function(){
      var emberobj = this.get('kvobject');
   //note the object I'm interested in is wrapped in some emberarray or object that is at emberobj[0]; 
      var arr = [];
      for (var key in emberobj[0]){ 
          if(emberobj[0].hasOwnProperty(key)){
               var pair = key + ' : ' + emberobj[0][key];
               arr.push(pair)
           }
      }
      return arr; 

   }
```

In my component template `templates/components/my-comp`, I do

```
  {{#each pair in keyvalues}}
    {{yield}}
  {{/each}}
```

But this throws an array, saying `the value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed function keyvalues()`.

Question: why can't I loop over the array returned from the function as a type of computed property?  Below, is the code from the linked-to answer that I modeled my code after.

```
App.IncrementForComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  numOfTimes: function(){
    var times = this.get('times');
    return new Array(parseInt(times));
  }.property('times')
});

Component template:
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/increment-for">
  {{#each time in numOfTimes}}
    {{ yield }}
  {{/each}}    
</script>

Component usage:
{{#increment-for times=2 }}
  <div>How goes it?</div>
{{/increment-for}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tack `.property()` on to the function so it knows to evaluate it instead of using it as is.

```
keyvalues: function(){
  var emberobj = this.get('kvobject');
 //note the object I'm interested in is wrapped in some emberarray or object that is at emberobj[0]; 
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in emberobj[0]){ 
      if(emberobj[0].hasOwnProperty(key)){
           var pair = key + ' : ' + emberobj[0][key];
           arr.push(pair)
       }
  }
  return arr; 

}.property()
```

Also in the newer versions of Ember it supports `each-in` which allows you to iterate over key value pairs of an object.

Comment: ok, thank you I will try each-in,  for the sake of completeness, the error message disappeared when I added `.property()` but  this `{{#each pair in keyvalues}}
    {{yield}}
  {{/each}}` is not actually displaying the key value pairs...so is there something else wrong with it?

Comment: forget it, didn't realize I'd actually have to do `{{ pair}}` thought just printing `{{yield}}` would do it all.